# Как исправить ошибку в коде?

Tags: python, системы-счисления

Запись числа 338 в системе счисления с основанием N содержит 3 цифры и оканчивается на 2. Чему равно максимально возможное основание системы счисления?

```
for i in range(3,1000):#перебираю основания систем счисления
  f=338
  s=''
  while f>0:#цикл переводит число в нужную систему счисления
    s=s+str(f%i)
    f=f//i
  if len(s)==3 and s[0]=="2":#s[0] , а не s[-1] тк питон задом наперед печатает числа
    print(i)
```

ответ: 16

но если делать перебор до 1000, то самое большое основание системы счисления это 338

Comment: Но ведь при 338-чной СС получится число 10, и оно не содержит две цифры и не оканчивается на 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы проверьте, что у вас в `s` получается. Заметьте, что для систем счисления с основанием больше `10` при добавлении очередного элемента **в строку** в неё в каких-то случаях **будет добавляться не один "знак", а больше** (если остаток будет больше `9`). Поэтому нельзя мерить количество знаков количеством элементов такой строки. **Добавляйте элементы в список**, а не в строку и проверяйте свойства списка. И тогда ваш код будет работать правильно и даст такой вывод:

```
7
8
12
14
16
```

> но если делать перебор до 1000, то самое большое основание системы
> счисления это 338

Но почему же? Разве основание системы счисления не может быть больше числа, которое в нём отображается? Я вполне могу написать, например, `1` в десятичной системе счисления или там `7` в шестнадцатеричной. А если вы имели в виду ответы вашего неправильного кода, то они вообще другие, `338` там в списке ответов нет.

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/NLE2Lw

```
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
  n = int(line)
  res = None

  for x in range(int(n**.5), 1, -1):
    if n >= x*x and n % x == 2:
      if n < x*x*x: res = x
      break

  print(f"{n}: {res if res is not None else 'No solution'}")
```

```
338: 16
16: No solution
1000000: 254
1: No solution
5: No solution
10: No solution
11: 3
77: 5
```